# cherrypy on raspberry very slower than pc

Tags: raspbian

i working on a project that convert raspberry to local company access point and web page viewer .

i create web site with cherrypy in pc and all thing work perfect and serve file with size 28MB take time 2 sec to display in client ..

but when i run this site to raspberry load web page is very slow and serve that file with size 28MB take time 11 sec to display in client ...

network interface in both pc and raspberry is same .

how i can optimize raspberry to be faster for cherrypy ?

Comment: Is your PC a 300 MHz Pentium 2?  Otherwise don't expect the Pi to equal it in performance. http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#performanceSpeed

Comment: If you had a PC which wasn't very obviously much faster than the pi, I'd say you were lucky it still works.  It boils down to whether or not what you are doing is really resource intensive -- it sounds like it isn't, but you have not explained in much detail.  In any case, I'd be pretty surprised to hear of anyone getting 14 MB/s of raw data out the pi's combined USB/ethernet bus, although in theory it should be possible.